# MsgSrvDoc links 404 on wiki: how to correct?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've noticed in the wiki page of [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_msgs) that the links to the message documentation are broken (404).

They lead to `http://docs.ros.org/en/move_base_msgs/html/action/MoveBase.html`

They should lead to `http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/move_base_msgs/html/action/MoveBase.html`

I tried to correct it on the wiki but it seems they are auto-generated.

```
<<MsgSrvDoc(move_base_msgs)>>

## AUTOGENERATED DON'T DELETE
## CategoryPackage
## CategoryPackageROSPKG
```

Does anyone knows how to make it correct or notify the right person that can correct it ? It seems this issue is global with every packages and every distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363702/msgsrvdoc-links-404-on-wiki:-how-to-correct-?/) by [simchanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28658/simchanu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-19**:
Looks like this is still fall-out from [Migration of docs.ros.org content into `/en` prefix](https://discourse.ros.org/t/migration-of-docs-ros-org-content-into-en-prefix/16829).

This is not limited to `move_base`.

I noticed the same when posting on Discourse, but assumed it would clear up after everything had been rebuilt or sorted out. Perhaps that's not the case.

Perhaps @tfoote can comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for noticing this it was a missed url element in the migration.

It's fixed in https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/pull/321 and should be live on the site.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simchanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28658/simchanu/) on 2020-10-21**:
To answer completely the question, I assume the best way to handle this kind of issue is contacting you ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-10-21**:
If there's a systematic issue like that on the wiki please file a ticket at: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues